# Is there anyway I can check the load time of a webpage in cpanel?

Tags: cpanel

I found that sometimes my website is slow, and I suspect that this is the web host's problem. But the web host insists on that the website is fast. The problem, I suspect, is that the website is fast sometimes, and slow most of the time. The people at web host would just measure the load time of a webpage when the page is responding fast and tell me that there is no problem at their end.

So, I am thinking about capture the load time for every webpage request, I am not sure whether is this information already available in cpanel ( I am using cpanel)? If yes, how can I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. cPanel cannot know how long a page takes too load.

There are too many variables that affect a page's performance. If it loads fast for the hosts, then it loads fast for the host but that may be because their network access is much more efficient to their own machines.

The best is to measure performance from an outside point such as [Google Page Speed](http://pagespeed.googlelabs.com/). Just enter your URL and it will even give you suggestions on how to improve it. Keep in mind that it will give you different speed ratings based on network conditions too, so test on Monday morning if you prefer better results ;)